# Different approach to utilize Angular Micro-Frontend remotes in the host Angular app

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

**Context:**

I have 2 Angular 13 applications, 1 as remote and the other as host and using Module Federation to configure both remote(creating mfe) and host.

All Module Federation examples directs us to load the remote module in the host like this

```
 {
    path: 'kpi',
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        remoteEntry:
          'http://localhost:58777/dist/megaHrx/remoteEntry.js',
        remoteName: 'mfe1',
        exposedModule: './KpiModule'
      }).then((m) => m.ChangeKpiModule)
  }
```

While my remote Module is as following:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ChangeKpiComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, ChangeKpiRoutingModule],
  providers: [AbbbbbService , StorageService]
})
export class ChangeKpiModule {}
```

**Question:**

This works and my Remote component `ChangeKpiComponent` gets rendered under the route `kpi` as expected, but what my intention is to use this `ChangeKpiComponent` via its selector `admin-reporting-change-kpi` and not by directly loading it via loadChildren in the Routing module.

Is there a way to do that ? If yes, How ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve that as follows:

- Expose the component itself also from the remote app (not only the module).
- Load it in your host app using the `loadRemoteModule` method.
- Create a [dynamic component](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) based on the returned type from `loadRemoteModule`.
- You can create a directive to reuse it anywhere in the host app:

```js
@Directive({ selector: '[adHost]' })
export class AdHostDirective {
  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    loadRemoteModule({
      remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:58777/dist/megaHrx/remoteEntry.js',
      remoteName: 'mfe1',
      exposedModule: './KpiComponent', // <<<< Use the component expose
    }).then((m) => {
      const componentType = m.ChangeKpiComponent; // <<<< The component's type here.

      // Create the component in this view-container:
      this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentType);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh I did not know we could expose components too ! This changes and simplifies soo much for me. Thanks !